# Firestore startAfter last snapshot is not working, if 2 or more documents have same field value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have a collection named 'test', which has multiple documents.
Each document has a unique name and a number field.
I have implemented pagination using query cursor. The query to get initial documents is as follows:

```
let lastDocument={};
 ref.collection("test").orderBy('number', 'desc').limit(3).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    lastDocument = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length-1];
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error getting documents", err);
  });
```

After getting the lastDocument, I paginate it as follows:

```
ref.collection("test").orderBy('number', 'desc').startAfter(lastDocument).limit(3); //lastDocument has the last document of the snapshot that was retrieved.
```

In my collection, if there are 2 or more documents which have same value of field 'number', then I don't get that document in the query result. Whereas, If I change the value of the field 'number', so as to make all the documents unique, I get all the results in batches(according to the limit clause) properly.

It's mentioned in the document as well, that, if multiple fields have same population value, the query won't work https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query

How should I modify the query, so as to get all documents in the result, even if 2 or more documents have same values for the field used in orderBy?

I am using:

`"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
"react-native": "^0.59.8",
"firebase": "^6.6.1",`

> Update: I have tested the queries on JSbin and it returns proper
>   results. I have issues when I use it in react native app with
>   react-native-firebase library. The pattern that I have recognised so
>   far is as follows: let's say, there are documents like below
>   {id:a,num:1},{id:b,num:2},{id:c,num:2},{id:d,num:2},{id:e,num:3},{id:f,num:4}
>   Then if I query for the first set with orderBy('num','desc') and limit
>   as 2, I'll get [a,b]. Now, if I query with the startAfter last
>   document as 'b' and limit as 2, then it will skip all the documents
>   after b, which have num same as that of b (i.e 2). So, it'll skip doc
>   [c,d] and return me [e,f]. This works fine on jsbin, but not on react
>   native using react-native-firebase library.

Please find the exact output for the code [here](https://jsbin.com/zunetehoxa/edit?js,console) on react-native below:

> "Got all results"
>
> "wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j => {\"index\":2,\"number\":2}"
>
> "kGC5cYPN1nKnZCcAb9oQ => {\"index\":6,\"number\":2}"
>
> "8Ek8iWCDQPPJ5s2n8PiQ => {\"index\":4,\"number\":2}"
>
> "mr7MdAygvuheF6AUtWma => {\"index\":1,\"number\":1}"
>
> "RCO5SvNn4fdoE49OKrIV => {\"index\":3,\"number\":1}"
>
> "CvVG7VP1hXTtcfdUaeNl => {\"index\":5,\"number\":1}"
>
> "Got first page"
>
> "wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j => {\"index\":2,\"number\":2}"
>
> "kGC5cYPN1nKnZCcAb9oQ => {\"index\":6,\"number\":2}"
>
> "Got second page"
>
> "mr7MdAygvuheF6AUtWma => {\"index\":1,\"number\":1}"
>
> "RCO5SvNn4fdoE49OKrIV => {\"index\":3,\"number\":1}"

**Note that it has skipped : "8Ek8iWCDQPPJ5s2n8PiQ => {\"index\":4,\"number\":2}"**

**Encountered one more issue in react-native-firebase library:**
If there is a map structure in the documents like below:

```
{
 subscribedUsers:{
 +1656666:true,
 +1657878:false,
 +1677676:true
 }
}
```

Now if I fire a query like below:

> db.collection("ownerUsers").where(`subscribedUsers.${phonenumber}` ,
>   '==' , true).limit(3).get();

The query returns 3 results.Now, if I try to get the next 3 results using startAfter clause like below, it works fine with firebase, but doesn't work with react-native-firebase library:

> db.collection("ownerUsers").where(subscribedUsers.${phonenumber} , '==' , true).startAfter(last).limit(3).get()

then I get the below error:

```
[Info] 11-10 21:38:42.631 21908 21967 I ReactNativeJS: 'Error getting documents', { [Error: Firestore: Client specified an invalid argument. (firestore/invalid-argument).]
```

Comment: Please make sure the code in your question is enough to reproduce the problem. Right now we have no way to know how `lastDocument` is initialized, and that is quite certainly key to your problem.

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the question with the required details. The lastDocument has the id and data.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce (https://jsbin.com/yicehob/2/edit?js,console). I added more info to my "answer". Let's continue the search under that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the `react-native-firebase` library. Check out the [issue on Github](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2854) to follow along. The issue is now marked as fixed, and this fix will be included in the next release (>5.5.6).

---

Old answer below...

---

The document you pass into `startAfter` needs to contain all the Firestore needs to determine where to start next. If the fields you filter on are not unique in the collection, the `DocumentSnapshot` will also need to contain the ID of the document. If your query is showing the first or second document matching the criteria, instead of the one after the one you're looking for, it's most likely because the ID is missing from `lastDocument`.

---

After your update, I tried reproducing the problem with this code:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var ref = db.collection("58783480").orderBy('number', 'desc');
ref.get().then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Got all results");
  snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id+' => '+JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
  });  
  var last;
  ref.limit(2).get().then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("Got first page");
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.id+' => '+JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
      last = doc;
    });
    ref.startAfter(last).limit(2).get().then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Got second page");
      snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id+' => '+JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
        last = doc;
      });
    });
  })
});
```

*live example [here](https://jsbin.com/yicehob/2/edit?js,console)*

But the output matches exactly with what I'd expect:

> Got all results
>
> wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j => {"index":2,"number":2}
>
> kGC5cYPN1nKnZCcAb9oQ => {"index":6,"number":2}
>
> 8Ek8iWCDQPPJ5s2n8PiQ => {"index":4,"number":2}
>
> mr7MdAygvuheF6AUtWma => {"index":1,"number":1}
>
> RCO5SvNn4fdoE49OKrIV => {"index":3,"number":1}
>
> CvVG7VP1hXTtcfdUaeNl => {"index":5,"number":1}
>
> Got first page
>
> wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j => {"index":2,"number":2}
>
> kGC5cYPN1nKnZCcAb9oQ => {"index":6,"number":2}
>
> Got second page
>
> 8Ek8iWCDQPPJ5s2n8PiQ => {"index":4,"number":2}
>
> mr7MdAygvuheF6AUtWma => {"index":1,"number":1}

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem within a jsbin, as shown in my updated answer. Can you see if you can reproduce the problem by using the same code and my database (find the settings in the jsbin) in react-native?

Comment: I used your db and code in a react native app and was able to reproduce the same issue. According to your jsbin, there are 3 entries with number:2 and 3 entries with number:1. If I get initial data with limit 1, then it returns doc with id: wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j, and if I startAfter this document and add limit 2, then it returns docs with ids ["mr7MdAygvuheF6AUtWma","RCO5SvNn4fdoE49OKrIV"] and skips docs with ids ["kGC5cYPN1nKnZCcAb9oQ","8Ek8iWCDQPPJ5s2n8PiQ"].  Is it an issue with react-native-firebase library that I am using?

Comment: I am able to get proper results, if I use my database on jsbin. The problem I am getting is only with react native app, where I am using react-native-firebase library

Comment: It sounds like it might be a good moment to file a bug on react-native-firebase in that case. I'll see if I can find sometihng in their code too, but the maintainers will definitely know better.

Comment: I did some browsing through the code, and it indeed seems that the library drops the document ID, which is what is needed for this to function properly. See https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/41d468ef5eddd5bdc2c9debc268ab5df2fd14b6c/packages/firestore/lib/FirestoreQuery.js#L38 (although it's definitely not easy to read). I'll file a bug.

Comment: On a separate note: I highly recommend that you show the actual code and its output, as I have done in my answer. Your descriptions are much harder to parse, than seeing the actual code and its output. In fact, can you edit your question to show the exact output (in the same format I used) when you run the same code I used against the same database?

Comment: Thanks Frank :). I have updated the question with the exact output of the code, using your db and code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had expected it to restart with `wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j`, but it instead skips `8Ek8iWCDQPPJ5s2n8PiQ`. I guess `startAt` would probably restart with `wbXwyLJheRfYXXWlY46j`. Btw, I filed a bug here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2854, and updated with the information you provided

Comment: I have encountered one more issue and have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please don't add more issues to the same question, as it confuses matters..

Comment: Sure. I have opened a new github issue for the other bug that I encountered: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2856

Comment: Please also open a new question here, as it's confusing to have both questions in a single post. For example, `react-native-firebase` fixed the original issue you reported here (and I then [reported on their repo](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2854)), while your second issue hasn't been addressed yet. They may be problems in a single use-case to you, but they're likely separate issues.

Comment: Sure Frank! I’ll open a new question. Thanks for getting a fix for this issue! 

Comment: How can I get the fix as I am on react-native-firebase v5.5.6? I can't upgrade to v6 of this library, as it's minimum react native version requirement is v6 and I am on react-native v0.59.8. I can't afford to upgrade everything. I am a novice, so could you please help?

Comment: If the fix was only released on 6.x, you'll need to upgrade to that version to get it. You could consider backporting it to 5.x yourself (it's an open-source repo after all), or ask on the bug whether a backport is forthcoming.